# jquery: get text of first <td> based on <tr> id

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I would like to be able to get the value of 1 or 2 based on the row id.

```
<tbody>
<tr data-uid="4584f83c-5ebe-4463-883e-4113b38e9ef3">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Commons</td>
    <td>Amherst</td>
    <td>Massachusetts</td>
    <td><a class="k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-edit" href="#"><span class="k-icon k-edit"></span>Edit</a><a class="k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-D" href="#"><span class=" "></span>D</a></td>
</tr>
<tr class="k-alt" data-uid="4146df62-1788-4296-8ff9-f8b523a4e844">
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Chase</td>
    <td>Amherst</td>
    <td>Massachusetts</td>
    <td><a class="k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-edit" href="#"><span class="k-icon k-edit"></span>Edit</a><a class="k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-D" href="#"><span class=" "></span>D</a></td>
</tr>
```

This is what I have tried:

```
var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr")); 
var propId = $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid").tbody.find("tr[data-uid='" + dataItem.uid + "']").first("td").html();
```

and

```
var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr")); 
var propId = $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid").tbody.find("tr[data-uid='" + dataItem.uid + "']").first("td").text();
```

The second one almost worked but it gave back all the values of the `TD`'s in the `TR`.

Comment: I tried this:
var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
var propId = $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid").tbody.find("tr[data-uid='" + dataItem.uid + "']").first("td").html();

Comment: As well as: 

var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
var propId = $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid").tbody.find("tr[data-uid='" + dataItem.uid + "']").first("td").text();

This almost worked but it gave back all the values of the TDs in the TR.

Comment: That code looks fine assuming `tbody` is a jquery object. can you add it to your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('tr[data-uid*="4584f83c-5ebe-4463-883e-4113b38e9ef3"] td:eq(0)').html();
```

**OR**

```
$('tr[data-uid*="4584f83c-5ebe-4463-883e-4113b38e9ef3"] td:eq(0)').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

something as simple as: `$('table tbody tr:eq(0) td:eq(0)').text();` remember all indices start at 0 so row 1 is actually row 0

Answer (score 0):

You have to select the correct `tr` by attribute using the attribute selector, then use the child selector for its `td` children, and finally `.first()` and `.text()`:

```
var id = $("tr[data-uid='...'] > td").first().text();
```

Comment: I tried the above suggestion and I get back the text of very TD within the TR.

Comment: @Mithrilhall: Isn't that what you want? The ID is in the first `td` of the appropriate `tr`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('tr[data-uid*="4584f83c-5ebe-4463-883e-4113b38e9ef3"]:first-child').html();
```